# Debugging Coroutines in C++20

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20

With the upcoming C++20 standard we will have coroutines at our disposal. What is the best way to debug code based on coroutines? What could be done to trace the call flow?

Comment: Can there be answer other than “Wait until `gdb` or similar supports them.”?

Comment: "*What is the best way to debug code based on coroutines? What could be done to trace the call flow?*" Wouldn't that depend on exactly *how* a piece of code uses them? I don't think anything special would be needed to debug generator coroutines. And if you're talking about async ones, they're just a fancy wrapper around an asynchronous callback, so you would largely debug them the way you debug such callbacks.

Comment: `printf` is all you need

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines are not magic. They just have a different function flow that's based on hidden code. Gdb and others can already debug them.

I'm not sure you understand how debuggers work, but it's simply that in every assembly code line, there's a line in your C++ source code associated with it. These links are called "debug symbols". The only question you need to ask is: Are there lines of code associated with your coroutines and their call flow? The answer is yes.

In conclusion: there's no reason for a standard debugger to not work with them. I don't even believe there's much to add to debuggers to make them support coroutines.

Comment: code compiled with coroutines differs in how local variables / function arguments are stored (depending on implementation, they are not on stack). For now, when I debug function with suspension points in it, all such variables are not accessible / not visible with gdb. Also, call stack is useless (of course). Another (higher level) languages debuggers reassemble call stack with async holes in it, and if we want this in gdb, some standartization efforts must be done in this direction.

Comment: gdb, specifically, lacks the ability to inspect the non-stack-allocated frames of coroutine functions. it doesn't display locals, it just shows a useless `void *frame_ptr` entry.

Comment: g++ / gdb 11.2 still says "variable is optimized out" when trying to inspect anything inside a coroutine: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99215. Really need a solution to this soon.